# Cross Origin request cancelled from composer rest server

Tags: cors, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

There is a business network running on hyperledger Fabric and it has APIs exposed via composer-rest-server with multi user mode on with github. When I try to authenticate through the composer rest servers and on successful login redirect, request to my django app gets cancelled with the below error. Django is being used to call the APIs.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at  (Reason: CORS header
>   ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

I want to know how can I enable cross origin request so that I can have separate application to call the rest services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS settings are specified in a file with a similar name to this: `~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/server/middleware.json`

As described here: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/middleware.json.html#cors-settings